# returning the last expression in a block

Tags: kotlin

I am learning the new and very beautiful language Kotlin and everything seems to be very logical and consistent. I only found one thing which seems like an arbitrary exception to the rule than a solid rule. But maybe I lack enough understanding some deeper reasons behind the rule.

I know that in `if-else` and `when` statements there are blocks of code, then the last expression is returned. In the next example `1` or `2` are returned depending on the condition - in our case it returns `1`.

```
val x = if (1 < 2) {println("something"); 1} else {println("something else"); 2}
```

On the other hand this does not hold for any code block. The next line assigns `y` not to `1` but to the whole block of code as a lambda.

```
val y = {println("something"); 1}
```

Similarly in function body, the last expression is not returned. This does not even compile.

```
fun z() : Int {
    println("something")
    1
}
```

So what exactly is the rule? Is it really so arbitrary like: if in `if-else` or `when` statement which is used as expression there is a block of code, then the last expression in the block is returned. Otherwise the last expression is not returned to outer scope. Or am I missing something?

Comment: that line does not assign `y` to anything. Perhaps it assigns something to `y`.

Comment: @MikeNakis My English is not perfect. I am not sure which is correct: Assign a value to a variable. Or assign a variable to a value. But I think it is easy to understand what I meant.:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you misunderstand the curly brackets `{}`, when around with all `flow-control` statement it is just a **block**, for example:

```
if (condition) { //block here
}
```

**WHEN** the `{}` is declared separately it is a **lambda** expression, for example:

```
val lambda: () -> Int = { 1 }; // lambda
```

**WHEN** you want to return a `lambda` in `if-else` expression, you must double the curly brackets `{}` or using parentheses `()` to distinguish between the **block** and the **lambda** expression or make the `{}` as lambda explicitly, for example:

```
val lambda1: () -> Int = if (condition) { { 1 } } else { { 2 } };
val lambda2: () -> Int = if (condition) ({ 1 }) else ({ 2 });
val lambda3: () -> Int = if (condition) { -> 1 } else { -> 2 };
```

> If a function does not return any useful value, its return type is `Unit`. `Unit` is a type with only one value - `Unit`. This value does not have to be returned **explicitly**.

On the other hand, a *common* `function` must have a explicit `return` statement if its return type if not a `Unit`:

```
fun z(): Int { return 1; }
```

Another case is a function return `Nothing`, the `return` statement don't allowed at all, because you can't create a `Nothing` instance, for example:

```
fun nothing(): Nothing {
    return ?;// a compile error raising
}
```

**WHEN** a function has only one expression then you can using [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) instead, for example:

```
fun z() = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably what I meant by my comment. `{}` has three (Or even more? Am I missing some?) distinct roles - it can be a block in a control flow statement or it can be a lambda or it can be a function body. And different rules apply to all of these cases. I do not mean to rant or complain, I will have to take it as it is. But this seems to me a bit of inconsistent language design flaw of otherwise perfect language.

Comment: My coding style take-away from this question is that I will try to avoid blocks in control flow statements when they are used as expressions. I am coming from C++ and Python realms and there is nothing like 'return the last expression in the block` so I will use `if` or `when` as an expression only when the returned expressions are trivial (without block), e.g. `a = if (x) y else z`. Otherwise I will use the full-blown syntax `if (x) {println("something"); a = y} else {println("something else"); a = z}` like we know from other languages.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between a lambda block and just a 'normal' block, in your case the "y" is just a lambda that needs to be executed to get the returned value:

```
val block: () -> Int = { 5 }
val five: Int = { 5 }()
val anotherFive = block()
```

So if you want a block that acts as a lambda, you can create a lambda and execute it right away with "()". This way, your "z" function would compile like so:

`fun z() : Int = {
       println("something")
       1
  }()`

(Which, of course, does not make much sense and is not very efficient)

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, V.K.  The choice is completely arbitrary.  Well, probably not completely arbitrary but related to parsing complexities arising from curly braces being chosen to denote both blocks and lambdas.

Actually, besides the case you make for block expressions, there also is the situation of (simple) blocks:  just group of statements enclosed in braces.  For example, Java supports (simple) blocks and you can write:

```
String toBeComputed ; {
    // Relatively long sequence of operations here
    toBeComputed= resultingValue ;
}
```

I use this idiom quite frequently because:

- It's not always convenient to extract the code into a function.
- Like a function, it delimits the code and documents its nature without introducing additional names or comments.
- Sometimes it's preferable to initialize two or more variables in tandem and introducing a result-value class with this specific purpose feels like an overkill.
- Also like a function it doesn't pollute the outer namespace with temporary variables only used internally.

Anecdotally, as Java does not support block expressions I would write the example as

```
int y ; {
    println("something");
    y= 1 ;
}
```

Other languages (ALGOL and Scala come to my mind) do support block expressions (and in the case of Scala also lambdas, but with a different syntax).  In these languages what you proposed (in Scala syntax)

```
val y= { println("something"); 1 }
```

is completely valid and does not require `()` to force a lambda to evaluate (because there is no lambda!).

In conclusion, Kotlin designers did choose to make the language less consistent than ALGOL and Scala in terms of blocks and block expression, probably in favor of convenience.

I hope my long response shows that what you expected from Kotlin was not illogical, just not the case because of some language design choice.  The principle of less surprise did not work this time.